# How to convert MS Graph charts embedded in Word document to Excel charts

Tags: charts, office-interop, word-automation, word-2013, excel-charts

I have a Word document (.doc) that contains charts in the form of MS Graph charts, that are embedded as OLE objects. When converting that document (using Save As) to .docx format, using Word 2007, all of these charts are successfully converted to Excel charts, as this is the default format for Word 2007 onwards. However, converting the original .doc file to .docx format using Word **2013**, the results are not the same - only about half of the charts are converted to Excel format, while the rest stay as embedded MS Graph chart OLE objects.

I have a larger .NET application that needs to convert the old-style charts to Excel format in .doc files it gets to interact with (by automating Word), and it can't do this reliably by simply upgrading the format. Is it possible to programmatically convert the remaining charts in MS Graph format to the new Excel format (the host document would be in docx/docm format by this time)? The solution would ideally work across any version from 2007 onwards.

I have searched this site, Google, and MSDN, but haven't found any functions to do this in the Word object model. Manually recreating Excel charts that are equivalent by copying the data, style and formatting from the OLE objects is possible, but not feasible for this application.

Comment: Have you found any workaround? I am stuck in more or less a same situation.

Comment: @ZunairZubair Unfortunately not, sorry.